# How do I include a .cpp/.h file pair in qnx momentics?

Tags: c++, include, qnx, momentics

Im new to QNX and and not experienced with larger software projects in general.
Im trying to include the tinyXML2 library into my QNX Momentics project. I have the .cpp and the .h file of the library but I dont understand how I should correctly include these files into my project so they can be referenced from my main code(included with an #include  statement)

hope someone can help

thanks

Comment: Im using QNX Momentics on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First you should put library source files (*.cpp and *.h) into /src/ for library building.
2. When you need to use this library in your project - just
   `#include "library_name/lib.h"`
   library header.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users, you need to download and copy both the files (`tinyxml2.h`, `tinyxml2.cpp`) into `/usr/include` directory to resolve the error.